# How do I make nodelet manager as fast as the individual nodes?

Tags: ros, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two nodelets that don't talk to each other at all. Neither subscribes to anything that the other publishes. I put them under a shared nodelet manager as the first step of a larger project to integrate them with a third nodelet.

I was surprised to discover that stapling the nodes into a single nodelet manager made them slower overall, even with a really high num_worker_threads.

nodelets.launch:

```
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="twin_nodelet_manager" args="manager"> 
        <param name="num_worker_threads" value="32" />
    </node>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="tweedledee" args="load wonderland/tweedledee twin_nodelet_manager" />
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="tweedledum" args="load wonderland/tweedledum twin_nodelet_manager" />
```

nodes.launch:

```
    <node pkg="wonderland" type="tweedledee" name="tweedledee" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="wonderland" type="tweedledum" name="tweedledum" output="screen"/>
```

Is this consistent with other people's experience? I assume I'm not giving the nodelet manager as much of the computer's resources as I gave the pair of nodes. Is there a way to increase that?

EDIT:

By "not as fast" I mean that the time elapsed during the main callback increased according to std::clock.

```
void mainCallback(msg) {
  double start = std::clock();
  // do stuff, publish
  double elapsed = ((double)std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("elapsed: " << elapsed);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242189/how-do-i-make-nodelet-manager-as-fast-as-the-individual-nodes?/) by [gabewb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27810/gabewb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-08-23**:
How did you measure the fact, that they are slower? When you open up `htop` do you see them running in separate threads?

**Comment by [gabewb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27810/gabewb/) on 2016-08-23**:
Edited to show method used for testing. I didn't run htop to see what resources the nodelets were getting - I'll let you know what I see.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
I don't think you can use `std::clock()` for this purpose. See this note fi (from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock)):

> if the current process is multithreaded and more than one execution core is available, `std::clock` time may advance faster than wall clock.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-23**:
In general I wouldn't use cpu time for benchmarking purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the use of std::clock(). The nodes themselves were single-threaded, but the nodelet manager is multithreaded, which throws off std::clock() by a lot.

Switched to std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(), and the problem no longer appears.

Thanks, gvdhoorn!

---

Originally posted by [gabewb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27810/gabewb/) with karma: 26 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1